# как вывести список в обратном порядке сверху вниз

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot

```html
Транкзакция на оплату

 Дата 17.11 18:17 
Сумма пополнения в руб  21
Сумма пополнения в LTC 0.00335167
!
Статус транзакции: 
|__________________|
Дата 17.11 03:19 
Сумма пополнения в руб  5555
Сумма пополнения в LTC 0.86442299
!
Статус транзакции: 
|__________________|
Дата 17.11 03:19 
Сумма пополнения в руб  5555
Сумма пополнения в LTC 0.86513403
!
Статус транзакции: Не оплачено
|__________________|
Дата 17.11 03:15 
Сумма пополнения в руб  2500
Сумма пополнения в LTC 0.38958476
!
Статус транзакции: Не оплачено
|__________________|
Дата 17.11 03:15 
Сумма пополнения в руб  2500
Сумма пополнения в LTC 0.38958475
!
Статус транзакции: Не оплачено
|__________________|
Дата 17.11 03:07 
Сумма пополнения в руб  4324
Сумма пополнения в LTC 0.67239454
!
Статус транзакции: Не оплачено
|__________________|
Дата 12.11 18:42 
Сумма пополнения в руб  5445
Сумма пополнения в LTC 0.78318375
!
Статус транзакции: Не оплачено
|__________________|
Дата 12.11 18:23 
Сумма пополнения в руб  56
Сумма пополнения в LTC 0.00802358
!
Статус транзакции: Не оплачено
```

**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**

```html
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains='history')
async def purchase_list(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.delete()
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    qiwi = Qiwi.objects.get(id = '1')

    user = await get_user(call.from_user.id)
    payment_list = await get_payments(call.from_user.id)
    payments = []
    for payment in payment_list:
        tz2 = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')
        payments.append(f'<b>Дата</b> <code>{payment.date.astimezone(tz2).strftime("%d.%m %H:%M")}</code> \n<b>Сумма пополнения в руб </b> <code>{payment.sum_amount}</code>\n<b>Сумма пополнения в LTC</b> <code>{payment.txnId}</code>\n\n➖➖➖➖➖\n<b>Статус транзакции:</b> <code>{payment.get_status_display()}</code>\n➖➖➖➖➖\n')

    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Обновить', callback_data='payment_history'), types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Назад', callback_data='history'), types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="проверить транзакцию", web_app=WebAppInfo(url="https://blockchair.com/ru/")))


        

    if payments:
        aa = '\n➖➖➖➖➖\n'.join(payments)
        await call.message.answer(f'<b>Транкзакция на оплату</b>\n\n {aa}', reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True)
    else:
        await call.message.answer(f'Tранзакции не найдены', reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True)

    await call.answer() #скрыть часики
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. О каком списке речь? Дополните ваш вопрос, сейчас не понятно, что требуется

Comment: вот этот список

Comment: или есть иной способ просматривать данные а то не удобно когда большой список смотреть текущею оплату

Comment: и дополнительный вопрос  запись ID_USER записывает того кто оплатил и кто бы не взял покупку она отображается    в корзине у последнего оплатившего товара , а при оплате всё корректно в становиться на своё место  и получается кто оформляет у того корзина пустая так как неправильно записывается в базу ID_USER